# Как запускать серию тестов JUnit строго последовательно?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit

Есть серия тестов. Я хочу, чтобы они использовали некоторый разделяемый объект. Первый тест его вычисляет, второй (и последующие) требуют его для своей работы. Похоже, что по умолчанию тесты запускаются в раздельных потоках и первый тест не успевает выполниться к началу второго.

Про @Before знаю, он плохо подходит, хотелось бы точный контроль за выполнением.

Вопрос: как явным образом указать, что все тесты выполняются последовательно?

```
/** shared object */
Object a;

@Test() //succeeds
public void testFoo() {
    a = foo();
    Assert.assertNotNull(a);
}

@Test()
public void testBar() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(a); //fails
    b = bar(a); //null pointer exception
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В общем - никак.  Тесты должны быть независимы друг от дружки. Если они зависят от последовательности запуска - Вы неверно понимаете концепцию юнит тестов.

Поэтому, их лучше писать так

```
@Test() //succeeds
// в этом тесте тестируется факт создания правильного объекта
public void testFoo() {
    Object a;
    a = foo();
    Assert.assertNotNull(a);
    // можно проверить другие поля объекта
}

@Test()
public void testBar() {
    Object a;
    a = foo();
    Assert.assertNotNull(a); //этот тест можно и пропустить, но лучше оставить
    // а вот тестить поля объекта уже не нужно
    // а теперь тестим код, который нуждается в этом объекте.
    b = bar(a); //null pointer exception
}
```

Но и эта схема "не очень правильная". В идеале пишут метод, который будет создавать объект и помещают его в `@Before` или что там предоставляет фреймворк.

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужен еще и [benchmark](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/junit-benchmarks.html) на каждый тест. Я хотел сэкономить на создании объектов. Похоже, придется повторять некоторые действия.

Comment: тесты отдельно, бенчмарки - отдельно. Задача тестов - проверить, что все правильно работает. А вот будет оно минуту или пол часа - не имеет значение (на самом деле для программиста имеет, сколько ему ждать проверки, но в теории тестов - не имеет).

А в бенчмарках проверять каждое поле не нужно. Иногда даже корректность результата (для этого есть тесты). Отладочный вывод может очень сильно исказить бенчмарк.

Comment: Ага, понял, что зря смешиваю.

Answer (score 8):

В JUnit есть аннотация `@FixMethodOrder`.
Попробуйте таким образом:

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class SomeTest {
    @Test
    public void aTest() {
    /*
    your code
    */
    }

    @Test
    public void bTest() {
    /*
    your code
    */
    }
}
```

Comment: @FixMethodOrder - работает!
У меня проблема была как думаю из-за параллельного выполнения тестов, 2 теста с обращением к одному и тому же счетчику метрик registry.counter("business_exceptions", Tags.empty());
Тесты предполагали последовательное выполнение в любом порядке, и тест в какой-то момент стал валится (выдавать не то значение счетчика) пока не поставил @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)

Comment: @Константин добро пожаловать на сайт :) Похоже, что вы вот к этому ответу написали комментарий, так что я его сюда и перенёс.

Comment: @Константин если у вас будут ещё вопросы по этой теме — задавайте их именно как [новые вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Для контекста можно дать ссылку на этот.

Answer (score 2):

В целом, как уже заметили, это сделать невозможно (да и неправильно будет).
Однако, если уж очень сильно хочется, то можно провернуть это через Suite`ы:

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;


@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        TestJUnitA.class,
        TestJUnitB.class
})
public class TestSuite  {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

В приведенном примере TestJUnitA-класс выполнится заведомо перед TestJUnitB

Answer (score 2):

Согласно идеологии, юнит тесты должны быть изолированы друг от друга, каждый тест это независимая единица, те что зависимы друг от друга это уже не совсем юнит тесты. Другой вопрос, что нередко система настолько сложная и запутанная, что не выловить взаимовлияние тестов происходящее на каких то очень низких не подлежащих макетированию уровнях и вычистить взаимодействие на уровне JVM сложно, а играться с `ClassLoaders` тоже геморно, я для такого [сделал маленький мавен плагин Jute](https://github.com/raydac/jute), который просто запускает каждый тестовый метод `JUnit` в отдельном внешнем процессе в "чистой" jvm