# Как выполнять тесты в определенной последовательности (codeception)?

Tags: php, codeception

Работаю над rest api и решил собственно учиться тестировать. Мое rest api использует aouth2 аутентификацию, поэтому везде необходим токен доступа.

Я написал успешный тест для получения токена, вот только незадача, есть другие тесты, которые выполняются до того как выполнится тест аутентификации и я получу токен доступа и они все валятся.

К сожалению я плохо знаю англ. язык, поэтому не смог сформулировать вопрос для поиска. 
Подскажите пожалуйста как в codeception можно задавать порядок выполнения тестов ?

Пример демонстрирует проблему, - аутентификация выполняется в самом конце.

[image: пример]

Comment: Тесты как бы должны быть независимыми. Т.е. ваши тесты должны нормально отрабатывать независимо от их порядка. Если для теста надо выполнить авторизацию - значит выполняете ее (например, в `setUp` методе), сама же авторизация может быть протестирована и потом. А вообще в `phpunit` можно передать файл конфигурации, где раписано какие тесты и в каком порядке надо выполнять

Comment: Возможно будет полезно http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/628529/182771

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От себя еще добавлю конкретно по теме:
https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2368

Тоесть необходимо создать хелпер (модуль), подключить его в конфигурации, пересобрать тесты и авторизация выполняется непосредственно в нем, перед всеми тестами.

Comment: А что, мой ответ перестал работать? )

Comment: К сожалению тут нельзя помечать 2 ответа одновременно.

Comment: Я специально если кому-то нужно отписал ответ по теме именно codeception с ссылкой на вопрос на гите.

Comment: ок, понял вас :)

Answer (score 4):

Тесты должны быть независимы друг от друга и выполняться в любом порядке.

Если для всех тестов необходима некоторая подготовка, то её нужно выделить в отдельный метод, который выполняется перед каждым тестом. Не знаю синтаксис для вашего фреймворка, но он должен быть.

Если не выполняется какое-то из предусловий теста или он завершается до проверки конечного результата, то это называется "блокирование теста" и тоже считается багом.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую найти.  А как делать в случае если нужно тестировать последовательно, разбивать как-то на отдельные куски ?

Comment: @Nepster объясните подробнее, почему нужно именно последовательно?

Comment: Сложно придумать подходящий пример на текущем проекте, но попробую сформулировать из предыдущего проекта.  К примеру есть некий сценарий у пользователя. Пополнить счет, активироваться, получить личный кабинет, получить какие-то возможности. Исходя из типа активации личный кабинет и возможности могут быть разные.

Comment: Тоесть тесты, которые тестируют пополнение счета, тестирую активацию и тестирую кабинет. До пополнения счета мы не можем активироваться, до активации у нас нет кабинета, до кабинет нет никаких возможностей.

Comment: @Nepster понял вас. Завтра подумаю и напишу подробнее, сейчас совсем спать валюсь.

Comment: @Nepster: пока что вы можете почитать, что мне отвечали на тот же вопрос, только про  Java: [Как запускать серию тестов JUnit строго последовательно?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/424055)

Comment: @Nepster так тестируйте отдельно. Например создать тест на проверку активации до пополнения счета, в котором нужно проверять на false и еще один тест где активация уже после пополнения счета и проверка идет на true. Данные в этом случае подсовываются фиктивные для проверки самой логики и правильной работы модулей.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Пошел изучать и пробовать.