# Как задать порядок приемочных тестов в Codeception

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, codeception, acceptance-tests

Знаю, что тесты должны быть максимально независимыми, но так не получается из-за достаточно сложного и взаимосвязанного алгоритма.

Есть ли какой-то способ определить последовательность запуска тестов в Codeception 2.2.9?

P.S.: до обновления, прошлый тестировщик вносил изменения в вендор в `testLoader()`, делал подгрузку файла с очередью из `acceptance.suite.yml`, но после последнего обновления это перестало работать, достаточно много изменений. Да и править код фреймворка плохая идея.

Comment: А тестировщику, который правил код сторонней библиотечки, надо оторвать ручечки и пришить их снова, но уже в плечики ;)

Answer (score 2):

Codeception позволяет делать тесты зависимыми друг от друга, определяя тем самым последовательность их выполнения.

Для этого вы во-первых должны описывать ваши тестовые сценарии в [Cest формате](http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Cest-Classes), а во-вторых использовать аннотацию [`@depends`](http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#dependencies) для указания зависимых тестов.

Предположим, вы хотите выполнить следующую последовательность действий:

1. Проверить, что форма аутентификации работает и войти в систему;
2. Проверить, что профиль пользователя отображается верно;
3. Проверить, что вы можете нормально выйти из системы.

Тогда ваш Cest файл может иметь вид:

```
<?php
class ProfileCest {
    public function login(\AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('log in');
        $I->amOnPage('/login');
        $I->fillField('Login:', 'foo');
        $I->fillField('Password:', 'bar');
        $I->click('Log in!');
        $I->seeLink('log out');
    }

    /**
     * @depends login
     */
    public function userProfile(\AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('see profile');
        $I->amOnPage('/profile');
        $I->see('Hi there! It\'s your profile.');
    }

    /**
     * @depends userProfile
     */
    public function logout(\AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('log out');
        $I->amOnPage('/');
        $I->click('log out');
        $I->seeLink('log in');
    }
}
```

**Замечание:**

Аннотация `@depends` задает не конкретный порядок выполнения тестовых сценариев, а **связи** между сценариями. Если в вашем наборе тестов есть несколько не связанных между собой сценариев, то они будут выполнены в произвольной последовательности.